# Error after adding cordova network plugin to Ionic Cordova app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm getting the following error:

```
Unknown provider: $cordovaNetworkProvider <- $cordovaNetwork <- SponsorsCtrl
```

When I check the root of my project via the console with cordova plugin list, the network plugin is among the installed plugins list:

```
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.0 "Network Information"
```

Controller:

```
.controller('SponsorsCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaNetwork) {
    var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline()
    var isOffline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline()
})
```

What could be the cause of it not being detected?

Comment: are you running it in device?

Comment: Show the declaration and injection of your app.controllers as well (from app.js)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you have ngCordova setup? It is required for `$cordovaNetwork` to work, since it is a wrapper for `cordova-plugin-network-information`.

You should have the following in the first line of the file that contains your controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```

The important part is the 'ngCordova' part. You can find further instructions on the ngCordova website [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/).

If you don't want to use `ngCordova`, you should follow the instructions outlined [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information#connectiontype).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the plugin like:

```
function checkConnection() { 
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type; 
    var states = {}; 
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection'; states[Connection.CELL] = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';
    alert('Connection.   type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/README.md